# Windows phone 8.1 : Upload files to google drive using service account in C#

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

We have to upload files to google drive using particular emailId i,e (xyz@gmail.com).

I am having two Question in my mind and expressed below

1) Can we can upload files to google drive using service account.

2) Can we Upload files to google drive using particular email id i,e (xyz@gmail.com) for example we different sites, Different Person's  we will visit the site and capture photos through their mobile and upload those images to google drive , These images should be upload to particular email id i,e (xyz@gmail.com)

Suggest me how we can implement any one of the above scenior.

Thanks for you help